# variable in closure but not able to access

Tags: javascript, node.js, closures

```
var net = require('net');
var redis = require('redis'); 
var redisClient = redis.createClient("redis://localhost:6379");

redisClient.on("connect",function(){
    console.log("Connected to Redis");
});

net.createServer(function(socket){
    console.log('CONNECTED: ' + socket.remoteAddress +':'+  socket.remotePort);
    var id = '';
    socket.on('data',function(data){
        console.log(id);
        if(id == '')
              test();
        else
           //do something else
    });
}).listen(10000,'');


function test(){
     redisClient.hgetall('12345',function(err,res){
         id = res.id;
     });
}
```

In this code why variable id is not closure when i call function test? Its giving an error id is undefined in test function. Am i understanding closures in the wrong way ?

Comment: You are understanding closures the wrong way. JavaScript scope is lexical and static. Calling a function does not make local scope variables available to the called function.

Comment: @Pointy i have edited the code. For the first packet of data i get id using the details in the data i received after that without making any calls to redis i want to continue the code. Can i do something like this.

Comment: No, you've still got exactly the same problem.

Comment: yes, but if i add var self =  this. and pass this function test change the id using  self.id. Is it a good practice to this. ?

Comment: If you make `id` not be a local variable but instead be a  property of an object, you can pass a reference to that object to `test()` and then that asynchronous call can modify the property value.

Answer (score 2):

The function `test` -- and all other functions -- only sees global variables, variables defined within the function itself and variables defined in enclosing scopes with regard to the function *definition*.

You don't see variables in the scope that *calls* the function. You will have to pass these variables as parameters if you want to make them accessible for the function.

Comment: is there any way that i can change the variable in parent scope from a function. i.e can i change id from test function?

Comment: @user3508612 in this case, no - the `test()` function itself is invoking another asynchronous operation. You can return values from synchronous functions, but in this case it just doesn't make sense.

Comment: i have updated the code. can i do something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, closures can't see variables defined in a separate function. variables are lexically (function) scoped (as mentioned by lex82 and Pointy).

You can only define `var id = ''` inside test() or pass the id variable in test() function.